# can I safely clone perl lib to another location on a computer?

Tags: perl, cpan

I have my own personal perl instance, using perlbrew and a local cpan instance.  I put in a bit of effort to get cpan to work for my local install.  I've configured code and tested it using this perl.

I now want to ensure anyone on the computer can use the perl code I wrote, meaning ensuring that the cpan modules I used are available to all, even those that can't access my home directory.

Unfortunately, I can't configure and use cpan as root user.  There are a few reasons why this would be difficult, but the biggest is that I am using my personal cert to authenticate myself as part of connecting to the CPAN repo (needed due to the configuration of the system).  I don't want to make my cert available to everyone for connecting to CPAN.

I'm wondering if, instead of fixing the root cpan instance and trying to hunt down all the modules I'm using with cpan, I can simply copy the modules I already have.  I'm running with the same perl version and on the same architecture, so the modules in my personal home directory should be the right ones.

The problem is that perllocal.pod seems to hard code locations relative to where my instal was done, so a simply copy paste is not enough.  Is there another easy way, possible a perl utility, to copy my local CPAN modules and perl lib directory over to the root perl lib directory?

Comment: Why don't you just give them permission to your `perlbrew`-installed `perl`. Then just continue to use `#!/home/ikegami/usr/perlbrew/perls/5.22.0t/bin/perl` or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, but why don't you just give them permission to your `perlbrew`-installed `perl`. Then just continue to use `#!/home/ikegami/usr/perlbrew/perls/5.22.0t/bin/perl` or whatever.

Comment: no one else can see my local install.  It's mounted only for me.  even root can't access it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know exactly what you have installed, you could have a look at [Dist::Surveyor](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Surveyor)

If you already know what all of your deps are, you can list them in a `cpanfile` and then take a snapshot with [Carton](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carton) and use the generated `cpanfile.snapshot` to install the correct versions in the new location

Answer (score 0):

you can clone the whole CPAN to your server for everyone to install
minicpan -l ~/CPAN -r http://ppm.activestate.com/CPAN/ [-f]